# Laravel 8 no actualiza la bbdd al hacer una petición POST

Tags: php, api, laravel-8, postman

Estoy haciendo una petición "POST" desde "Postman" proporcionando un "Body" con JSON" a una ruta definida en "api.php", pero a la hora de comprobar si los datos veo que no se actualizan en la tabla correspondiente, aunque la respuesta de la petición "POST" si que son correctos.

Petición "POST":
[image: Petición "POST"]

Ruta de "api.php":

```
Route::post('/person', [PersonController::class, 'edit']);
```

Método "edit" de "PersonControler":

```
public function edit(Request $request) {
    $person = Person::getDNIPerson($request -> dni);

    $request -> validate([
        'address' => 'required|max:40',
        'location' => 'required|max:20',
        'province' => 'required|max:10',
        'phone' => 'required|integer',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    $person -> address = $request -> address;
    $person -> location = $request -> location;
    $person -> province = $request -> province;
    $person -> phone = $request -> phone;
    $person -> email = $request -> email;

    $person -> save();

    return $person;
}
```

Respuesta de la petición "POST":
[image: Respuesta petición "POST"]

Petición "GET":
[image: Petición "GET"]

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? En "Postman" no se muestra ningún error y mostrando los campos del método "edit" en principio todos se asignan bien.

Edición 1:

Modelo "Person":

```
class Person extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'person';
    protected $fillable = ['dni', 'name', 'surnames', 'address', 'location', 'province', 'phone', 'email', 'postal_code'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function legalGuardian() {
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\Models\LegalGuardian', 'person', 'dni');
    }

    public static function getDNIPerson($person) {
        return Person::where('dni', '=', $person) -> first();
    }

    protected static function newFactory(): PersonFactory {
        return PersonFactory::new();
    }
}
```

Edición 2:

Tabla "Person":

```
class CreatePersonTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('person', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table -> string('dni', 9);
            $table -> string('name');
            $table -> string('surnames');
            $table -> string('address');
            $table -> string('location');
            $table -> string('province');
            $table -> string('phone');
            $table -> string('email');
            $table -> string('postal_code');

            $table -> primary('dni');

            $table -> timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('person');
    }
}
```

Comment: `getDNIPerson` ¿Qué hace? ¿Qué devuelve? La clase `Person` ¿tiene `$fillable` los campos que quieres?

Comment: "getDNIPerson()" es básicamente un "find" generado para buscar una persona por su DNI, este valor DNI es la clave primaria de la tabla, por lo que nunca se va a repetir y devuelve la fila de la tabla. el fillable si tiene los campos que podrías ser editables.

Comment: Creo que el problema puede ser el `->get()` que haces en tu `getDNIPerson`, ya que `find()` (el método que se suele usar cuando buscas por id), hace un `->first()`. El método `->get()` retorna una collection ("array") y `->first()` devuelve el objeto. Dicho eso, cambia `->get()` por `->first()`

Comment: Cualquier cosa nos cuentas! Si el problema persiste, intentaré replicar tu código

Comment: He cambiado en el método getDNIPerson del model el "-> get()" por "-> first()" y he quitado en el controlador el "-> first()", pero sigue sin actualizarse la tabla. Entiendo por donde ibas, pero en el controlador me había asegurado de estar trabajando con un objetos sólo y no con una colección, pero así queda más limpio. (Lo edito sobre la pregunta para descartarlo, muchas gracias por la observación).

Comment: Buenas! He replicado tu código al 90% igual. Y me hace el update sin problemas. Solamente no he usado el `HasFactory` (me da error de Not Found, pero como no voy hacer uso de factorías, sin problemas), por eso digo que al 90%. Usando el mismo método `getDNIPerson` (con `->first()`. `->get()` me da error) y todo correcto. Claramente usando el PostMan. Eso sí, en el header de postman tuve que añadir/editar `Content-Type: application/json`, pero no creo que sea tampoco tu error porque sino te diría `dni not found in request` o algo parecido

Comment: Yo el "HasFactory" si que lo uso, de hecho el usuario que estoy editando está creado con un "Seeder". También tengo el cambio hecho de "first()" por "get()", pero no me funciona, haré pruebas directamente en la bbdd para ver que puede estar pasando. Gracias por el soporte.

Comment: Si, si. Si eso lo entiendo, el porqué del Factory. ¿Conseguiste dar con el clavo? Me parece mazo raro todo, te diría "puede ser que no le esté llegando bien `request->dni`? Y que no encuentra a nadie con ese DNI, pero entonces te daría error de `address on null` o algo así. Te diría ¿El Middleware de api? Pero tampoco, porque sino petaría antes. La verdad que tengo mucha curiosidad de saber dónde está el fallo. Si das con él, coméntamelo o responde a tu propia pregunta, por fa! Jajajaja

Comment: Al final lo he podido arreglar, si te fijas en la 2ª captura que puse en la pregunta, la respuesta que devolvía llegaba bien, pero es una especie de falso positivo, realmente no se actualizaba la tabla, pero tampoco se mostraba ningún error. "Middleware" aun no le he metido ninguno, cuando le añada el "auth" lo voy a pasar mal. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he podido solucionar el problema que tenía, explico las modificaciones que he realizado.

Primero he cambiado el tipo de petición de "POST" a "PUT".
Segundo he cambiado la tabla "Person", para añadirle un 'id' con autoincremento y el campo 'dni' lo que cambiado de "primary key" a "unique".

Aparentemente al ejecutar "-> save();" busca el elemento por 'id' para hacer el "Update" en la base de datos, al no tenerlo, no actualizaba la tabla.

Comment: Pues... Debería tirarte error de que no encuentra a la persona por DNI que le pasas. A mi sí que me tiraba error el `getDNIPerson` de que no encontrada por `id` y tuve que añadirle `$primaryKey = "dni"` pero como a ti no te tiraba errores y no te decía `Can't save() on null` pues me supuse que lo tenías visto y solventado. Pero vamos el tipo de petición no le afecta, prueba solo añadir el `$primaryKey`. Y deja tu código cómo lo tienes hasta ahora. Bueno saberlo que `->save()` SIEMPRE buscará por el primaryKey y no por el "encontrado".

Comment: Vale, yo di con el `Can't save() on null` cuando usaba el `Person::find($request->dni)`. Y supuse que find, hacía (y devolvía) lo mismo que un `where` solo que buscaba por `id` y en el `where` le decimos lo que queremos buscar.

Comment: Por eso mismo me creé yo la función con el where, para poder hacer la búsqueda personalizada por el dni, pero tampoco caí en la cuenta de que el save() no funciona como el los seeders, y aunque haya una clave primaria definida, intenta buscarlo por id, pero ya te digo que no me devolvía ningún error el Postman, ni Laravel ni Android Studio.